# Unable to fetch nested values from axios api response

Tags: reactjs, json, api, axios

I am able to fetch the response.data object but when I try to fetch the values inside it, I get undefined as out put. Here is my code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { injectable } from 'inversify';
import "reflect-metadata";

interface Configuration {
  EnableForgetPassword?: string;
}

interface Data {
  configuration?: Configuration[];
  permissions?: string[];
}

interface ConfigData {
  data: Data;
 
}

@injectable()
class ConfigService {
  private _config: ConfigData = {
    data: {
      configuration: [{ EnableForgetPassword: "False" }],
      permissions: []
    },
    
  }
  private _permissions: string[] = []
  private _configuration: any = {};

  async loadConfigData(): Promise<void> {
    
      const response = await axios.get<ConfigData>('https://run.mocky.io/v3/74946531-e762-4f42-990d-2e73b73f9176');
      const config = response.data; 
      
      console.log(config);
      console.log(config.data.permissions); // throws error
  
}
}
```

here is my response json

```
{ 

data: {
  
  configuration:[{"EnableForgetPassword":"True"}],
  permissions:["Global.Settings","User.Create"]
  
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions')
> at ConfigService.loadConfigData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON properties need to be in "double quotes", so your JSON is not valid and Axios isn't able to handle it as JSON. This is what your server *should* be returning:

```
{
  "data": {
    "configuration": [
      {
        "EnableForgetPassword": "True"
      }
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "Global.Settings",
      "User.Create"
    ]
  }
}
```